# How can I pass a preprocessor directive from ctypes?

Tags: c, preprocessor-directive

I have some C code that is wrapped in a preprocessor directive:

```
#if defined(TEST)
// do stuff
#endif
```

and I need to execute `do stuff` from Python via ctypes - is there any way I can define `TEST`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing at all to do with `ctypes` or python. ctypes only deals with already compiled libraries and allows you to call functions in them. If you want to execute a function that is only conditionally defined you'll have to compile the library with the right directives set.

In gcc that would be something like `gcc -D TEST <rest as usual>`